# Mipmaps and Nearest filtering result in darker image

Tags: opengl

I am loading images into OpenGL app.Usually I am using Linear filtering but now testing nearest I found the resulting image is significantly darker than the original one.Btw,it also seems to me that the linear filtering causes some brightness loose too.Here are examples:

**Linear filtering :**
[image: Linear filtering]

**Nearest filtering :**
[image: Nearest filtering]

Original image:
[image: Original image]

Now, I am setting mipmaps levels (to 4 ).I found that when not using mipmaps the original brightness is intact.What can be the problem?Is it related to gamma correction?

Here is the code for image load and mipmap generation:

```
                    ILinfo imageInfo;

        iluGetImageInfo(&imageInfo);
        iluFlipImage();

        if (imageInfo.Format == IL_RGB)
        {
            ilConvertImage(IL_BGRA, IL_UNSIGNED_BYTE);
        }
        else if (imageInfo.Format == IL_RGBA)
        {
            ilConvertImage(IL_BGRA, IL_UNSIGNED_BYTE);

        }

        iluGetImageInfo(&imageInfo);

        glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

        glGenTextures(1, &textureName);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureName);

        glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,numMipMapLevels,GL_RGBA8,imageInfo.Width,imageInfo.Height);
        glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,0,0,imageInfo.Width,imageInfo.Height,GL_BGRA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,imageInfo.Data);

        /* ==================================== */
        // Trilinear filtering by default

        if(smooth){
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        }else{
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        }

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

I am also running MSAA pass in a custom FBO but it looks to be irrelevant to the issue as I tested also with MSAA turned off and the same problem persists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your code it looks like you create a mipmapped texture (with 4 mipmap levels as you say) but then only set the image for the first level. This means all the other level's images are undefined. When then using [`GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexParameter.xml), it will access the two mipmap levels that best fit the pixel-texel-ratio (the `MIPMAP_LINEAR`-part) and then pick a single nearest texel from each level (the `NEAREST`-part) and interpolate those.

From your image it looks like the unspecified mipmap levels are just black, so you get an interpolation between the texture color and black, thus a darkened texture (well, they could actually contain anything and the texturing shouldn't even work since the texture is incomplete, but maybe immutable storage behaves different in this regard). When not using mipmaps (thus only creating a single level with `glTexStorage`), there will only be a single level used in the filtering (even if using a mipmapped filter), which of course has a valid image.

If you intend to use some kind of mipmapping, then you should actually set the texture image for each and every mipmap level (or set the top-level image and do a [`glGenerateMipmap`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGenerateMipmap.xml) call afterwards). If you just wanted to use real nearest neighbour filtering, then just use `GL_NEAREST` (I've never actually seen much practical use for all the other mipmap filters except for the real trilinear filter `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR`).

Comment: HaHa, I skipped " glGenerateMipmap" for the nearest case :) Now I see it works.Thanks man.

Comment: @MichaelIV But keep in mind if you want to do nearest filtering, then use nearest filtering. Is there a particular reason you're using `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR` at all?

Comment: Well,I recall reading somewhere it is better (in terms of visual quality)for nearest filtering mipmap interpolation than the nearest_mipmap_nearest...Am I mistaken? :)

Comment: @MichaelIV Well, yeah it uses linear interpolation between mipmap levels and, well, linear is better than nearest, no? It just amounts to the question how far you can conceptually still call this nearest filtering. But if you got a good reason to use it, it's ok. I just wanted to make sure its use isn't based on some wrong assumptions about the supposed need for using a mipmapped filter when the texture has mipmaps (because encountering all those `GL_..._MIPMAP_...` is rather rare if it isn't the `LINEAR-LINEAR` version and people come up with the weirdest assumptions in lack of knowledge).